# How to set main class displayed by `jps` when using JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jconsole

How do I set the name of the main class displayed by `jps` or JConsole when starting a Java process via JNI?

In C, I get a class and main method like so:

```
jclass main_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, java_main_class);
...
jmethodID main_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, main_class, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

And start Java like this:

```
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, main_class, main_method, main_args);
```

My process works well, but when I run `jps` I do not see the Main class. For example:

```
$ jps -l
30056 
30065 sun.tools.jps.Jps
```

I also see a blank string when looking for the process in JConsole.

However, I do see my args with `jps`:

```
$ jps -lv
30068  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx500m ...
30070 sun.tools.jps.Jps -Dapplication.home=
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with 'C' so please remove the 'c' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the system property `sun.java.command`

For example: `-Dsun.java.command=com.example.Main`

I found this by searching through the [source code for the `java` executable](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/a70af3aae22b/src/share/bin/java.c#l286) that is distributed with the JDK.